# Is $G=\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ a subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$?

Tags: group-theory

I know that $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ is a cyclic group of order $p-1$. Also the set of upper triangular 2 by 2 matrices form a subgroup of $G$. Let's denote it by $H$. How do I see that $\mathbb{F}_P^{\times}\leqslant H\leqslant G$?

Comment: Elements $a\in \Bbb F_p^\times$ correspond to $\pmatrix{a&0\\0&a}$

Comment: You can embed $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ as diagonal matrices.

Comment: Or, if you demand determinant $1$, you may map $a$ to $\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&a^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thanks @StinkingBishop I was wondering the same thing!